# Regular Investment - Historical Data - Sanity Check

Tags: investing

I'm attempting to calculate the returns I'd have received from investing in the FTSE 250 from 1990 - 2019 (1st January in each case).

I believe my maths is correct, but I'd like a sanity check as I can't actually find a calculator that I can used to validate this.

This is the data I have available to me:

```
Date        Open        High        Low         Close       Adj Close
01/01/1990  £2,663.30   £2,721.20   £2,663.30   £2,709.40   £2,709.40
```

I'm taking the amount I want to invest each week and dividing it by the adjusted close price (`£100 / £2,709.40 = 0.03691`) to give me the number of shares that I own. I do this on a regular basis over the different weeks and keep track of the total number of shares I own. I then decide the point I want to sell and take the total number of shares I own and multiply by the adjusted close price to give me the total value of my portfolio.

Does this sound correct?

Comment: You would also need to account for dividends and splits, if any.